# Access User's Friends with only App Access_token in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As mentioned in [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/) an app can access user's friend's id with an app access_token. But when I try to access friends of a user by

> www.graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=friendlists&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 104
  } 
}
```

How can I access a user's friendlist with only app access token?

Comment: so, where is the access token? i can't see it anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: have you tried removing the "www" from the URL and using just https://graph.facebook.com/...

Comment: Yes I have tried with https:// and used the graph explorer. I get the same result

Comment: try debugging your access token with the access token debugger tool. also get a new access token from the graph api explorer

Comment: Actually I am accessing the API using code in python. So every time I run the code, a new Access token is fetched from the facebook server. Can you give the syntax as to how you will fetch the friend list of a user with the app access token?

Comment: are you sure you are using the app token correctly?

Comment: Yes, actually I decided to reset the secret key. Earlier I wasn't able to access posts and feed. But now I am able to access them. But still friend list is not accessible. Why wasn't the earlier key not working?

Comment: it sounds like a permissions issue then.. sometimes facebook spits out weird error messages, make sure you have the required permissions. access token debugger shows them if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the field "friends"?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=friends&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you requirement is just to fetch user's friends and their facebook ids, you can get them here.

Comment: I get an error.{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation", 
    "type": "FacebookApiException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}

Comment: Check if the user access token has expired. 
You can check this here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken